# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.BarCodeScanner.Constants')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I work with React-native Expo `"sdkVersion": "35.0.0"`. Now I am facing the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.BarCodeScanner.Constants')` for the code for react-native app with camera component (initial fragment):

```
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
...
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Expo changed its API.
Now we need to install a separate dependency:

```
npm i --save expo-barcode-scanner
```

And then to import `BarCodeScanner` object independently for your component like this:

```
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
```